# Quedarme con el Id autogenerado de un Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

Usando Sql Server 2012.

Estoy haciendo un insert en una tabla en la cual el id es autogenerado. Lo que quiero lograr es al mismo tiempo de hacer el insert guardarme el ID autogenerado en una variable. En el ejemplo tal vez quede mas claro lo que quiero lograr.

```
    --BLOQUE CALLE
    declare @IdCalle int = (select Dir_Calles.id from dbo.Dir_Calles where Nombre like @NombreCalle) 

    if (@IdCalle is null)
        begin
@IdCalle =  insert into dbo.Dir_Calles values (@Pais, @Estado , @NombreCalle, 
            'Sin descripcion', 1, @FechaActual)
        end
```

Comment: Agrega el código que llevas y el engine de SQL que estás usando

Comment: ¿En PHP? ¿Qué SGBD utilizas? ¿MySQL? ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No uses el clásico `@@IDENTITY` ya que tienes un serio problema cuando hay triggers involucrados que hacen inserciones en tablas que también tienen columnas del tipo `IDENTITY`, no obtendrás el valor de la tabla que te interesa sino el del último `IDENTITY` insertado. Para evitar esto, ya te lo han indicado, tiene el [`@@SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), que te asegura el valor que estas esperando.

Sin embargo, hay ciertos escenarios dónde [`@@SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) no funcionará adecuadamente o tal vez no te sea útil:

1. En caso que tu motor tuviera este [bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019779/you-may-receive-incorrect-values-when-using-scope-identity-and-identit)
2. O en caso que necesitarás insertar múltiples filas y necesitarás todos los ids.

Para esto, podría hacer uso de la clausula `OUTPUT` de la siguiente forma

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE (id INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.Dir_Calles (Col1, Col2, Nombre, col4, Col5, Col6) OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @IDs 
SELECT  @Pais, 
        @Estado, 
        @NombreCalle, 
        'Sin descripcion', 
        1, 
        @FechaActual
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from dbo.Dir_Calles where Nombre like @NombreCalle);

SELECT  *
    FROM @IDs
```

Al usar `OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @IDs` estamos indicando que todos los `id` ya generados se salven en una tabla en memoria `@IDs`, lo cual sirve para el caso de una única u múltiples filas insertadas

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la forma en la que lo haría yo para evitar problemas de concurrencia.

```
    DECLARE @IdCalle int;

    insert into dbo.Dir_Calles 
    SELECT @Pais, @Estado , @NombreCalle, 'Sin descripcion', 1, @FechaActual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(select Dir_Calles.id from dbo.Dir_Calles where Nombre like @NombreCalle);

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
        SET @idCalle = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    ELSE
        SET @IdCalle = (select Dir_Calles.id from dbo.Dir_Calles where Nombre like @NombreCalle);

    SELECT @IdCalle;
```

Asegurate de comprender bien la diferencia entre `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT`, y `@@IDENTITY`. El no conocerlas podría darte resultados incorrectos.

También te recomiendo revisar la cláusula OUTPUT que podría servirte, pero necesitarías usar una variable tipo tabla.

Answer (score 1):

despues de hacer el insert, recuperas el id con scope_identity:

```
insert into dbo.Dir_Calles values (@Pais, @Estado , @NombreCalle, 
        'Sin descripcion', 1, @FechaActual)

select @IdCalle = scope_identity()
```

puedes encontrar mas información en:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017