# existe alguna otra forma de capturar los valores identity aparte de @@identity, IDENT_CURRENT ,SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Tags: sql-server

Quiero insertar unos  datos a una tabla maestro detalle donde la tabla detalle tiene  asu vez otro detalles es decir
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL problema  esta cuando quiero un insertar datos a la tabla  detalle prueba ya que  depende del iddetalle_detalle  de la tabla detalle examen 2 por que puede  darse  el caso  de que detalle 2  tenga  varios registros y al usar @@identity o IDENT_CURRENT  o SCOPE_IDENTITY solo  toma el ultimo valor de identity  de la tabla  dos por lo  que si hay  varios detalle  en la  tabla  2  no  servira

Comment: Hola Mario, he notado que las últimas 5 preguntas que has hecho tiene que ver con esta dificultad que tienes a la hora de obtener el @@IDENTITY, no sé si son exactamente iguales, si lo son te recomiendo que las elimines y dejes una sola, la más completa. Por otro lado hace unos días te sugerí en los comentarios que veas esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418947/usar-identity-en-una-variable-para-capturar-el-userid-y-con-el-insertar-a-otra-t que creo responde a tu inquietud. ¿Has podido verla?

Comment: Regularmente lo que hago es un while dentro de mi sp, cada iteración inserto y obtengo el id que le corresponde, aun que puedes usar el OUTPUT, que puedes usar para insertar múltiples registros y el resultado enviarlo a una temporal, [OUTPUT Clauset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-output-into-with-a-simple-insert-statement)

Comment: Patricio Moracho   @@IDENTITY  y  el Scope_Identity  solo  obtiene el ultimo valor generado y yo  no quiero el  ultimo sino todos los  valores  generados en mi tabla detalle_examen2  para  colocarlor correctamente en mi tabla detalle prueba

Comment: Patricio Moracho veo que tiemes  respondido este https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262267/quedarme-con-el-id-autogenerado-de-un-insert/262305#262305

Comment: @PatricioMoracho lo que  quiero  va  realcionado a lo que tienen contestado aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262267/quedarme-con-el-id-autogenerado-de-un-insert/262305#262305 quiero guardar  varios identity  y luego  insertar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar una sequencia (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), para tener más control sobre los id's de las tablas en el código de sus procedimientos.

Para ejemplos de cómo utilizar la sequencia en su código y modelo ver: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

`Scope_Identity` va a devolver el último valor utilizado en el campo identidad tras una inserción en la sesión.

Es decir, si insertas en la tabla 1 y consultas `Scope_Identity` tendrás el valor insertado en el campo identidad de la tabla 1, pero si posteriormente insertas en la tabla 2 y consultas `Scope_Identity` te devolverá el valor insertado en el campo identidad de la tabla 2.

Si vuelves a insertar en la tabla 3, lo que te devuelve `Scope_Identity` es el último valor insertado en la tabla 3.

Por tanto, si deseas utilizar un valor concreto, debes guardarte en una variable el `Scope_Identity` que te interese antes de grabar en otra tabla (o en la misma).

Algo así:

```
DECLARE @LastIdentity int;

INSERT INTO Table1 ....

SET @LastIdentity = Scope_Identity

INSERT INTO Table2 (IdRelacionado, Valor) VALUES (@Lastidentity, 'Valor 1')
INSERT INTO Table2 (IdRelacionado, Valor) VALUES (@Lastidentity, 'Valor 2')
INSERT INTO Table2 (IdRelacionado, Valor) VALUES (@Lastidentity, 'Valor 3')
```

Así todos los valores de la tabla 2 tienen el mismo valor en el campo `IdRelacionado`.